# BeautifulSoup get_text only i want

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<dd>

    <span class="link_txt">

        <a href="/movie/sdb/browsing/bmovie.nhn?genre=2">판타지</a><!-- N=a:nol.genre,r:1 -->, 

        <a href="/movie/sdb/browsing/bmovie.nhn?genre=1">드라마</a><!-- N=a:nol.genre,r:2 -->

    </span>

    <span class="split">|</span>
            141분
    <span class="split">|</span>
        2018.08.01 개봉

</dd>**strong text**
```

how can i get only 141분(text) in < dd > tags

another text, i use find_all("tag", class_="name")

but, this < dd > 141분(text) don't have class

'get_text' result is 판타지, 드라마, 141분, 2018.08.01 개봉

i want only 141분(text)

---

Answer (score 1):

As you see, the text `141분` is first sibling of first tag with `<span>` with class `split`. So we will select all tags with class `split`, get first one (`[0]`), and get `nextSibling` of that one:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<dd>

    <span class="link_txt">

        <a href="/movie/sdb/browsing/bmovie.nhn?genre=2">판타지</a><!-- N=a:nol.genre,r:1 -->,

        <a href="/movie/sdb/browsing/bmovie.nhn?genre=1">드라마</a><!-- N=a:nol.genre,r:2 -->

    </span>

    <span class="split">|</span>
            141분
    <span class="split">|</span>
        2018.08.01 개봉

</dd>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select('.split')[0].nextSibling.strip())
```

Prints:

```
141분
```

Answer (score 0):

If `<span class="link_txt">` is unique you can use that as an identifier.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<dd>
    <span class="link_txt">
        <a href="/movie/sdb/browsing/bmovie.nhn?genre=2">판타지</a><!-- N=a:nol.genre,r:1 -->,
        <a href="/movie/sdb/browsing/bmovie.nhn?genre=1">드라마</a><!-- N=a:nol.genre,r:2 -->
    </span>
    <span class="split">|</span>
            141분
    <span class="split">|</span>
        2018.08.01 개봉
</dd>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find("span", class_='link_txt').findNext("span").nextSibling.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
141분
```